# How can I write a Protractor test for a listed tab element where it checks if it's active or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webdriver, protractor

I receive the following 'failure' when I run my protractor test:

> Expected '' to equal 'active'.

I'm basically testing for if a certain link element has an 'active' class (which it does! -I checked the dom using dev tools)

This is view.html:

```
<li class="active"> 
  <a href="#public1' data-toggle="tab"> All Stacks </a>
</li>
```

This is what I've tried in the test.js:

```
var allStacksTab = element(by.linkText("All Stacks"));    
expect(allStacksTab.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('active');
```

Can someone tell me what i'm dong wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Link itself doesn't have `active` class, parent `<li>` element has it. You could update expectation to get class of link's parent element:

```
var allStacksTab = element(by.linkText("All Stacks"));    
expect(allStacksTab.element(by.xpath('..')).getAttribute('class')).toEqual('active');
```

Comment: xpath should be avoided inside protractor everytime you can, for several reasons:

It's slower.
It's hardly maintainable.
it's hardly readable

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage promises fine:

```
var allStacksTab = element(by.linkText("All Stacks"));    
expect(allStacksTab.getAttribute('class')).to.become('active');
```